# How to share files between Windows and MacOS with dual boot

Tags: mac, windows-7, filesystems, file-sharing

I have MacOS snow leopard and Windows 7 installed on same hard drive(on a iMac). I want to have a folder that is shared between them where I can write data, not only read. Is this possible? On windows partition MacOS says that I don't have permission to write and on Mac partition Windows says same thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a Fat32 partition from either mac or windows you should be able to both read and write to it from either OS.

Comment: Ok, I will try. The problem is with write access not with partition type because Windows can read from Mac partition and Mac can read from Windows partition.

Comment: @Felics: the lack of write access is due to the partition type (or more accurately, the limited support for those partition types under the other OS).

Answer (score 0):

You could create an ext3 partition.
With the proper drivers, both MacOS and Windows can read and write to files in a ext3 partition.
(["Use a Linux file system for Mac/PC drive sharing"](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040214000632173))

- drivers for MacOS that can read and write and ext3 partitions: [How do I mount ext2/ext3 partitions in Mac OS X Snow Leopard?](https://superuser.com/questions/53533/how-do-i-mount-ext2-ext3-partitions-in-mac-os-x-snow-leopard)
- drivers for Windows that can read and write ext3 partitions: [ext2fsd.com](http://www.ext2fsd.com/), [fs-driver.org](http://www.fs-driver.org/), [Mount ext3fs in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/8298/mount-ext3fs-in-windows)

You might also look at the other options listed at
[Lifehacker: "A Comprehensive Guide to Sharing Your Data Across Multi-Booting Windows, Mac, and Linux PCs"](http://lifehacker.com/5702815/the-complete-guide-to-sharing-your-data-across-multiple-operating-systems).

Answer (score -1):

My answer is simply to format a flash drive to FAT 32 put it into a spare USB Port ( I recommend a 3.0 USB flash drive and 3.0 USB port )You can add to and remove from both drives. I then sync my devices from my Mac boot drive using iTunes.

Comment: Why use a flash drive when you have your hard drive inside the computer that both operating systems can access? This is a bad solution and should not be used in this scenario.