# How to automount an ext filesystem in macOS

Tags: macos, hard-drive, command-line, filesystems, mount

**TL;DR** This question is about **auto mounting** partitions with file systems non native to macOS.

I'm presently running macOS 10.12.x and I can successfully mount an external SATA disk formatted with an ext4 file system to my MBP thanks to this  [dude](https://github.com/alperakcan/fuse-ext2).  I'm able to read / write to the disk without any issues.

However, I'd like to automount the drive / partition / filesystem using the utilities provided by macOS.  I've seen numerous articles of people auto mounting network shares such as SMB NIS etc.

I am aware this can be done on a GNU/Linux box using tools such as `usbmount` and `udev`.  I've heard there is a paid program *$40* USD that might do what I am looking for.

However, it would be ideal to get this external USB drive auto mounted using the native tools provided by macOS or using some **FREE** tools that could be provided by [homebrew](http://brew.sh).

From my understanding macOS relies on

```
/etc/auto_master
```

to auto mount the resources using the **automountd** launch daemon.

I added the below entry to the above stated file,

```
/- auto_resources -nobrowse,nosuid
```

Then created an `auto_resources` file with the below contents

```
/../mnt/external-samsung-1tb -fstype=fuse-ext2 /dev/disk2s2
```

And finally I run `sudo -E automount -cv` to remount all the auto mounted filesystems on macOS, and I see the below output,

```
automount: /net updated
automount: /mnt/external-samsung-1tb updated
automount: no unmounts
```

However when I do `ls -lah /mnt/external-samsung-1tb`

I don't see the files listed.  And **yes** there are files on the system as I verified by manually mounting the drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read ext3 filesystem on Mac OS X Snow Leopard](https://superuser.com/questions/322411/read-ext3-filesystem-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard)

Comment: @tripleee did you even read my question?  Because if you did, then you would have realized this question pertains to **auto mounting** a non native macOS partition **NOT** getting it mounted manually using a command from CLI.

cheers 
Chris

Comment: related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210198/mount-ext4-on-el-capitan