# Netgear ReadyNAS Duo V1: corrupt root - any chance to mount or recover using Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, nas, readyboost

My ReadyNas by Netgear is giving me "root corrupt". It won't boot anymore.
I'm wondering what my options to recover my data are. I suppose everything is still on the disk(s) but how can I mount the disk on my Mac to copy everything over?
The filesystem is an "ext2 with 16kb block size".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/53533/how-do-i-mount-ext2-ext3-partitions-in-mac-os-x-snow-leopard) on how to mount Ext2 on Mac. if that fails download  linux live CD of your choice (mint, ubuntu, etc) and boot from it to mount your drive and copy your data off. while you are at it, you might want to run 'fsck -f' on it to make sure the filesystem is healthy, since you are showing signs of disk corruption.